# Adding value to a polygon layer with a feature of the nearest polygon of another layer

Tags: qgis

I have two polygon vector layers, shown below in purple and orange. In the orange layer, each feature has a height value that I want added to the nearest purple feature.

[image: Features]

Ideally, a new vector layer is made consisting of the features from the purple layer with the added height value from the nearest feature from the orange layer. But updating the purple layer will also suffice.

Comment: Join attributes by location (Vector menu > Data Management Tools) will do this. Or NNJoin plugin.

Comment: That only works for values that touch or intersect both geometries, not the ones that are nearby.